# Run ipython notebook from a remote server

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, remote-server

I'm trying to run a ipython notebook from my remote server(Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits on Amazon EC2).

I **can** access to ipython notebook via ssh tunnelling as described in [coderwall blog](https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg):

`remote$ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889`

`local$ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 remote_user@remote_host`

However I **can't** have a simple access using http protocol as described in the [official doc](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/notebook/public_server.html) or this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/5183133)

`remote$ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889`

And point my local browser to `http://mypublicip:8889`, the browser fails without any warning.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To resolve this problem, I needed to:

1. Run the notebook server listening on all IP addresses adding cli flag **--ip=***:

   `remote$ipython notebook --no-browser --ip=* --port=8889`
2. Add inbound rule to the amazon ec2 instance in order to listen to port 8889.

   `+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
   | Type            | Protocol | Port Range | Source    |
   +=================+==========+============+===========+
   | Custom TCP Rule | TCP      | 8889       | 0.0.0.0/0 |
   +-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+`

*Of course now it's better to add authentification as the port is listening to all ip adresses*

Comment: Escaping the star is needed for some shells.

Answer (score 4):

As Monkpit wrote below, your shell might try to glob `*` character. In that case you should write `--ip=\*`- Explicitly adding ip address to localhost also helped:

```
 ipython notebook --no-browser --ip=localhost  --port=7777
```

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because the shell tries to expand the glob `*`. Replace with `--ip=\*` to escape the glob and you can accept connections from any IP.

Comment: Perfect answer! Just change `--ip=localhost` to `--ip=yourip` and it should be good.